# Windows 2008 R2 restarts on own, no errors logged

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, server-crashes

In the last 2 days my dedicated server (Windows Web Server 2008 R2) has crashed twice and restarted.

I've looked in the Event Logs and there's nothing logged leading up to it.I'm very technical, but not a trained server administrator.

I have a dedicated server since my site is active enough to require one.  Since nothing is logged, how am I supposed to determine the cause of it so I can prevent it from continuing to happen?

It's not Windows Updates, automatic updates are disabled.  It's definitely a crash because in the Event Log I see:

> "The previous system shutdown at 9:25:13 PM on ‎3/‎3/‎2012 was unexpected.".

Comment: what brand of server and does it have ASR type software installed.  I so you may be able to look at the drac\ilo etc logs to see what may have happened

Answer (score 1):

I think that could be a BSOD not logged in the Event log, from my point of view could be an hardware related problem, like RAM or CPU Error. You should check hardware of your server with a memtest for example ...

Comment: +1. Agree on hardware - that ora crap driver. But more likely hardware. Pull server and check.

Comment: Thanks, I will run some tests that's what I was thinking too.  2 faulty servers in one year if that's the case.  Talk about bad luck lol

Comment: And here I am 2 years later looking up the same problem. Forgot I had this problem before. My solution last time was to get a new server, looks like that'll have to be my solution this time.